# How to correctly extract part of a string js?

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have a URL and I need to isolate a certain value from it, and to be more precise, the value after `numberType=`.

There may or may not be an ampersand after this value. How can I implement this with a generic function?

Examples

```
http://localhost:8080/type/3259/?filters=901&numberType=77

http://localhost:8080/type/3259/?filters=901&numberType=77&somethingElse=string
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: use browsers `URL` Web API ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class do the heavy lifting for you:

```js
const input = 'http://localhost:8080/type/3259/?filters=901&numberType=77';
const parsed = new URL(input);
console.log(parsed.searchParams.get('numberType'));
```